# How to control volume in android?

Tags: android, controls, media-player, volume

Android has the Hardware button for controlling volume (increase/decrease).
I want to same functionality by using buttons in my application with visual volume control and it should be disappeared after some time (in sec).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `AudioManager` class.  Developer doc is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). Depending on which volume you want to adjust (ringer/media) you may need to change the audiomode via `AudioManager`.

Finally, to make the buttons disappear just use View.GONE on them.  I would create a `Runnable` in the `onClickListener` and use a `postDelayed` to make the `View` disappear.