# Volume Control plugin

Tags: android, ionic2

Hello I want to make my Android application turning up and down volume. Is there any plugin to help me do so?

https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-volume-control -> I found this, but I can't make it work on Android (only iOS)

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/ -> This seems to work only on music files

Comment: Use Android's own AudioManager to handle different types of volumes. (E.g. Media, Ringer etc.) You shouldn't need a plugin to handle a system specific control... Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117051/how-to-control-volume-in-android

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible to use Android AudioManager in Ionic2?

Comment: Sorry mate did not notice the ionic2 tag, maybe make your question clearer to say it's using the ionic2 Framework?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670524/how-to-turn-the-volume-to-max-programmatically-on-android).